# Terraform Datasource oci_core_volumes module return string of a function

Tags: terraform, tolist

I am calling Terraform `oci_core_volumes module` to query block storage volumes, in the response, I am expecting id list of the volumes, but it returned a function `tolist` instead, how to execute it and get the ids in the function? Is there something like `eval` in Bash?

Code:

```
data "oci_core_volumes" "sas_volumes" {
    compartment_id = var.compartment_id
    display_name = "sas-lab_volume_0"
}
```

snippet of response:

```
volume_all_ids = tolist([
  {
    "auto_tuned_vpus_per_gb" = ""
    "availability_domain" = "ayQE:US-ASHBURN-AD-1"
    "backup_policy_id" = ""
    "block_volume_replicas" = tolist([])
    "block_volume_replicas_deletion" = false
    "compartment_id" = "ocid1.compartment.oc1..aaaaaaaaxxxxxx"
    "defined_tags" = tomap({
      "Oracle-Tags.CreatedBy" = "azuread-test/xxxxxxxxxx"
      "Oracle-Tags.CreatedOn" = "2021-11-06T03:58:38.510Z"
    })
    "display_name" = "sas-lab_volume_0"
    "freeform_tags" = tomap({
      "application" = "SAS"
      "automation:autoShutdown" = "false"
      "client" = "test"
      "compliance:PCI" = "false"
      "compliance:PII" = "false"
      "repository" = "terraform"
    })
    "id" = "ocid1.volume.oc1.iad.xxxxxxxxxxx"
    "is_auto_tune_enabled" = false
    "is_hydrated" = true
    "kms_key_id" = ""
    "size_in_gbs" = "50"
    "size_in_mbs" = "51200"
    "source_details" = tolist([])
    "state" = "AVAILABLE"
    "system_tags" = tomap({})
    "time_created" = "2021-11-06 03:58:39.209 +0000 UTC"
    "volume_backup_id" = ""
    "volume_group_id" = ""
    "vpus_per_gb" = "10"
  },
])
```

Comment: `tolist([])` means that terraform is trying to make a possibly mixed type list in a valid list in the sense of terraform, [which expect all element to be of the same type](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/tolist.html). So, in short, your output means that you have a list of objects as a return. You can use the [splat expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/splat.html) of terraform to get what you need. e.g. `volume_all_ids[*].id`

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It fixed my problem.